# Matlab Dynamically changing Audio player sample rate

Tags: matlab, real-time, audio-processing

I am working on a project in matlab to take a predetermined audio file and change the sample rate dynamically from data generated in real time. I have hit a very stubborn roadblock with the dsp.audioplayer object. It doesn't allow change in either the sample rate or the sample size once it's state is locked. My thoughts right now are to vary the sample size that I pull from the wav file and scale it using a fir rate conversion filter. Is this an option worth perusing? Are there any other ways around this problem?

Comment: If anyone has this problem in the future, the method I suggested was successful. Just read the audio with wavread, vary your sample size, and use the fir rate conversion filter to scale the sample to the appropriate size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest MATLAB release samplerate is tunable in dsp.audioplayer. Tunable Means you can change the property value after the object is locked.

Your workaround is good when this is not possible.